# Get text from a row that contains a unique condition to the first occurrence of a row that contains a repeated word in a file

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I ask you for help in solving this problem via command line or `bash` script.

I'm interested in the part of the file that goes from a line that contains a certain condition (unique, in this case two words) up to the next first line that contains a certain string (present many times in the file)

My file looks like this:

```
HEAD
Some text
MODEL 1
row1
row2
row3
row4
ENDMODEL
Some text
MODEL 2
row1
row2
row3
row4
ENDMODEL
Some text
MODEL 3
row1
row2
row3
row4
ENDMODEL
Some text
MODEL 4
row1
row2
row3
row4
ENDMODEL
Some text
END
```

I would like to extract from `MODEL 3` to the next `ENDMODEL`. So far I have tried various approaches with `grep`, `sed` and `awk`; for example I managed to get the line where `MODEL 3` appears

```
grep -n 'MODEL. * 3 \ | 3. * MODEL' myfile.txt | cut -d: -f 1
```

or, using the known number of lines, I can get the text that interests me

```
awk 'NR> = 17 && NR <= 22' myfile.txt
```

but unfortunately I am very far from the solution.

---

**EDIT**
I received an answer and a comment with a possible solution both working, so first of all thanks to the two people who solved my problem.

However I would like to be able to select the line which contains `MODEL 3` using `MODEL` and `3` as separate words.
What is the way to do it?

Comment: Wouldn't `awk '/^MODEL 3$/,/^ENDMODEL$/' file` work for you? If not please show your expected output in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One `sed` idea to print all lines within a range specified by the strings `MODEL 3` and `ENDMODEL`:

```
$ sed -n '/^MODEL 3$/,/^ENDMODEL$/p' myfile.txt
MODEL 3
row1
row2
row3
row4
ENDMODEL
```

Assuming the first pattern is derived from a variable:

```
$ startptn='MODEL 3'
$ sed -n "/^${startptn}$/,/^ENDMODEL$/p" myfile.txt
MODEL 3
row1
row2
row3
row4
ENDMODEL
```

---

Between new requirements and a comment from the OP:

- the strings `MODEL` and `3` are to be treated as separate strings (on the same line)
- case insensitivity is nice to have
- going to assume there may be other characters on the line besides `MODEL` and `3`
- going to assume that `MODEL` comes before `3`

Updated sample data file like such:

```
$ cat myfile.txt
HEAD
Some text
MODEL 1
row1 a
ENDMODEL
Some text
MODEL 2
row1 b
ENDMODEL
Some text
this is a MODEL #3 car     # should match from here ...
row1 c                     #
ENDMODEL                   # to here
Some text
MODEL 4
row1 d
ENDMODEL
Some text
END
Some text
MODEL   3                  # should match from here ...
row1 e                     #
ENDMODEL                   # to here
Some text
```

Updating the `sed` idea, using variables to contain the 2 search patterns:

```
$ p1=ModEl
$ p2=3
$ sed -n "/.*${p1}.*${p2}.*/I,/^ENDMODEL$/p" myfile.txt
this is a MODEL #3 car
row1 c
ENDMODEL
MODEL   3
row1 e
ENDMODEL
```

**NOTE**: The `I` designates case insensitive matching for the start of the range.

Comment: Wow! It works!
But I would like to make it a little more general. Actually `MODEL` and `3` are at a number of spaces that I might not know (actually in this case it's easy because you just have to open the file and count them). I would like to be able to select the line that contains both `MODEL` and `3` as separate words.
In the meantime, thanks for your solution!

Comment: please update the question with these additional details and more sample input (along with expected output); does the non-sensical `'I have a Model #3 car that runs'` match your criteria of `MODEL` (case insensitive?) + `3` existing on the same line?

Comment: I have updated my question. I had not thought about these possibilities and I am satisfied with the simplest solution (whether it is case sensitive or insensitive). Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2):

> However I would like to be able to select the line which contains MODEL 3 using `MODEL` and `3` as separate words. What is the way to do it?

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk -v m="MODEL" -v n=3 '$0 ~ "^" m " " n "$",/^ENDMODEL$/' file

MODEL 3
row1
row2
row3
row4
ENDMODEL
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/\<MODEL\>/!b;/\<3\>/!b;:a;N;/^ENDMODEL$/M!ba;p' file
```

This is a filtering operation, so turn off implicit printing by setting the `-n` option.

Do not begin processing until a line contains the word `MODEL`.

Do not begin processing until that line also contains the string `3`.

Append all following lines until a line containing only `ENDMODEL`.

Print the result and repeat.

N.B. The range operator `/from/,/to/` does almost the same but may print lines even when the end of the range does not exist. In which case it will print until the end of file.

Answer (score 0):

why only read it vertically ? if it's not too gigantic, you can even semi-flatten it like

```
{mawk/mawk2/gawk} 'BEGIN { FS="^$"; RS="ENDMODEL\n"; } 

    match($0, /\n[^\n]*[Mm][Oo][Dd][Ee][Ll][^\n]*[3]/) { 

       print substr($0, RSTART + 1) "ENDMODEL"; }'
```